# Fetched data failed to reach the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I trying to fetch data from API with React+Redux, but for some reason, data fails to render, even though i see it comes in console (with redux-logger)
It looks like for some reason, reducer doesn't change areLoading value to false - and data doesn't reach page. But I can't figure our where is the mistake, everything is seems right.

Component:

```
class Posts extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.postsFetch();
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>

                {this.props.data.map(function(post, i) {
                    return (
                        <div className="tale" key={i}>
                            <p className="title" key={i}>{post.title}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.posts,
        gotError: state.postsError,
        areLoading: state.postsLoading
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { postsFetch })(Posts);
```

Reducers:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    areLoading: false,
    gotError: false,
    items: []
}
export function postsError(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "POSTS_REQUEST_FAILURE":
            return {
                ...state,
                gotError: true    
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function postsLoading(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "POSTS_REQUEST_LOADING":
            return {
                ...state,
                areLoading: true    
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function posts(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "POSTS_REQUEST_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                areLoading: false,
                items: action.data
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

If I change my return statement to "return action.areLoading = false", and after that return action.data, everything works. But this solutions seems not right.

Actions:

```
export function postsError() {
    return {
        type: "POSTS_REQUEST_FAILURE",
    };
}

export function postsLoading() {
    return {
        type: "POSTS_REQUEST_LOADING",
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
    };
}

export function posts(data) {
    return {
        type: "POSTS_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
        data
    };
}

export function postsFetch() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(postsLoading());
    }
}
```

Middleware:

```
export const apiCallMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    const { url, ...rest } = action;

    if (!url) return next(action)

    next({ type: "POSTS_REQUEST_LOADING" })

    axios(url)
        .then(response => {
            const data = response.data
            next({ type: "POSTS_REQUEST_SUCCESS", data })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next({ ...rest, type: "POSTS_REQUEST_FAILURE" })
        })
}
```

I searched for a solutions on forum, but none of them seems to help me. I also new to React+Redux, sorry for a newbie question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in your combineReducers function? Do all other actions and reducers function as expected?

Comment: Why do you have three reducers for one Ajax request?

Comment: I had tried to write one reducer instead of three, and it makes no difference.

Comment: combineReducers function code 

`export default combineReducers({
    posts,
    postsError,
    postsLoading
});` 
And it works well, together with function which connects middlewares.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `data` into the `posts` action as an object and the reducer doesn't recognize a `data` key when you're doing `action.data`. I believe you have to change `data` to `data: data` in two places.

In the middleware:

```
next({ type: "POSTS_REQUEST_SUCCESS", data: data })
```

In the `posts` action:

```
export function posts(data) {
    return {
        type: "POSTS_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
        data: data                    //<---------
    };
}
```

and the reducer can now access the key `data` from `action` like so:

```
case "POSTS_REQUEST_SUCCESS":
  return {
    ...state,
    areLoading: false,
    items: action.data
  }
```

Comment: While there may be some truth to this answer, the code suggestion is off the mark.  The question uses ES6 object shorthand that is interpreted to the exact same code you wrote.  The original code is the idiomatic preferred style in React. I haven't spotted the problem with the code yet, but this change should have no effect.  The use of other ES6 features indicate that there is no issue overall re: support thereof.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was the problem.

Here

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.posts,
        gotError: state.postsError,
        areLoading: state.postsLoading
    };
};
```

i got links to state.post object.

Changing it to

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.posts.items,
        gotError: state.posts.gotError,
        areLoading: state.posts.areLoading
    };
};
```

make it to look on object properties, instead of the whole object

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to log your state under mapStateToProps like **console.log(state);** and use the exact property into return statement. I believe there is some issue.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        data: state.posts,
        gotError: state.postsError,
        areLoading: state.postsLoading
    };
};
```